# Mysql Database - sorting Dataoutput with dropdown box/boxes and search fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, select

I guess I don't know how to ask the right question, so the last hours brought no results... :-( 
here is my job:

I have db with appartment owners  AND a page where they are listed. All works and looks fine.
Now I would like:

 a select fiel or dropdown box with options to choose certain appartment typs
Lets say displaying only appartments for 2-4 people.
In the appartement db is a table with a field like for_max_people

The table is like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>
```

id | name  | year | homepage       | for_max_people | 
 1  |  red      | 2017 |  www.page1.html   |         2-4      | 
 2  |  blue   | 2016 |  www.page2.html  |         1-2      | 
 3  |  grey   | 2014 |  www.page3.html  |         2-4      | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

So the standard view would be all appartements -  (~ 300) But I would like to have an option to select certain parameter.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
  <option value="2-4">App. 2-4 People</option>
  <option value="4-6">App. 3-6 People</option>
</select>
</form>
```

So,
my question is not about - how to populate the select fields from database...
rather how to do the query that the selection will change the view of the table grid with the appartments shown...

Hope thats understandable...

What would the question be??? 
I can I did (!!!)  google it, but I always get a solution to fill the select / dropdown fields !

What expression / words to search for?
Of course a fiddle would be perfect...

Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onchange` event of the select and call a function which changes the values according to the selected option.

```
<select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control" onchange="updateTable();">
```

Within the `updateTable` function, you request the new data from the DB and then put them into the table. You should pass your filter as a parameter when requesting the new data, e.g. `data.php?filter=2-4`.

For the SQL query: You can use a `WHERE` condition and only select results where the value of column `for_max_people` equals what you've entered.

**Note:** Please make sure to use **prepared Statements** and also validate your user input, you don't know what a malicious user might send to you. A good way to do this to use `PDO`.